# How do I update address composite in MS CRM?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

**Problem**
I am trying to get my accounts to update the composite address with the new address. Al the fields in the customer address show the new values but the composite address shows the old address.

**Desired Result:**
Composite field updates to the new address upon changing the address fields

**Actual Result:**
Composite field shows the old address

**Things I've Tried:**

1. Updating the address
2. Deleting The Address and creating a new one (BAD IDEA)
3. Setting all fields to the default values when the account was created
4. Setting the composite field directly
5. Setting the version number to the default 0x00003F3F
6. Setting all address fields to null

**Current Code:**

```
    Entity theAccount = proxy.Retrieve("account", Guid.Parse("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"), new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ColumnSet(true));
Guid address1_id = theAccount.Attributes.ContainsKey("address1_addressid") ? (Guid)theAccount.Attributes["address1_addressid"] : Guid.Empty;

Entity theAddress = new Entity()
{
    LogicalName = "customeraddress",
    Id = address1_id
};
theAddress.Attributes["line1"] = null;
theAddress.Attributes["line2"] = null;
theAddress.Attributes["line3"] = null;
theAddress.Attributes["city"] = null;
theAddress.Attributes["stateorprovince"] = null;
theAddress.Attributes["country"] = null;
theAddress.Attributes["county"] = null;
theAddress.Attributes["postofficebox"] = null;
theAddress.Attributes["postalcode"] = null;
theAddress.Attributes["composite"] = null;

proxy.Update(theAddress);

theAddress.Attributes["line1"] = "1 New Street";
theAddress.Attributes["line2"] = null;
theAddress.Attributes["line3"] = null;
theAddress.Attributes["city"] = "New City";
theAddress.Attributes["stateorprovince"] = "New State";
theAddress.Attributes["country"] = "New Country";
theAddress.Attributes["county"] = null;
theAddress.Attributes["postofficebox"] = null;
theAddress.Attributes["postalcode"] = "1234";

proxy.Update(theAddress);
```

**Question**
How do I successfully change the address composite field in Microsoft Dynamic CRM upon updating the address fields

Comment: When you retrieve the record after the second Update, the composite field remains null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update the address fields of the Account record, not the CustomerAddress.

i.e.

```
Entity theAccount = new Entity("account", "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX");

theAccount["address1_line1"] = null;
theAccount["address1_line2"] = null;
theAccount["address1_line3"] = null;
theAccount["address1_city"] = null;
theAccount["address1_stateorprovince"] = null;
theAccount["address1_country"] = null;
theAccount["address1_county"] = null;
theAccount["address1_postofficebox"] = null;
theAccount["address1_postalcode"] = null;
theAccount["address1_composite"] = null;

proxy.Update(theAccount);

theAccount["address1_line1"] = "1 New Street";
theAccount["address1_line2"] = null;
theAccount["address1_line3"] = null;
theAccount["address1_city"] = "New City";
theAccount["address1_stateorprovince"] = "New State";
theAccount["address1_country"] = "New Country";
theAccount["address1_county"] = null;
theAccount["address1_postofficebox"] = null;
theAccount["address1_postalcode"] = "1234";

proxy.Update(theAccount);
```

If this you're doing is a real-time operation of some kind taking place while the form is open, you also might need to invoke `Xrm.Page.data.refresh(false)` for the new data to show up.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got stuck on having to clear the customeraddress rather than on the account. Been stuck on this for a week :S